# mysql query takes to much time

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I want to optimize this query becouse it takes to much time to return records

```
SELECT 
    u.*, 
    s.legal_name AS structure_name, 
    ui.id AS userinfo_id, 
    ui.structure_id AS structure_id, 
    ui.lrn_user, 
    ui.gender, 
    ui.fiscal_code, 
    ui.prov, 
    ui.phone, 
    ui.school_name, 
    ui.school_codice_meccanografico, 
    us.status, us.date AS status_date, 
    CONCAT(u.lastname,' ',u.firstname) AS fullname, 
    CONCAT(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) AS display_name, 
    uu.username AS created_by_name, 
    g.group_names, 
    IF(u.website_id = 0,'Sito Web principale', w.name) AS website_name 
FROM fcf_users AS u 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT 
        gu.user_id, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(gg.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS group_names 
    FROM fcf_user_user_groups gu 
    JOIN fcf_user_groups gg ON gg.id = gu.group_id 
    GROUP BY user_id 
) g ON g.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN fcf_users_userinfo AS ui ON ui.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN fcf_users_user_statuses AS us ON us.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN fcf_structures_structures AS s ON s.id = ui.structure_id 
LEFT JOIN fcf_users AS uu ON uu.id = u.created_by 
LEFT JOIN fcf_websites AS w ON w.id = u.website_id 
WHERE 
    u.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM fcf_user_user_groups WHERE group_id = '8') 
    AND u.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM fcf_user_user_groups WHERE group_id = '8') 
    AND ui.lrn_user = '0' 
ORDER BY fullname ASC 
LIMIT 0,25
```

If anyone can help, thanks

Comment: Properly formatting your query is a first step towards optimization.

Comment: Type faster? Or see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query?__=1753130441

Comment: In addition, as well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: Your `where` clause has the same `IN` condition twice.

Comment: i removed ```IN``` but i still takes to much time

Answer (score 0):

Turn it inside-out.  That is, *first* use a 'derived' table to locate 25 users you want.  *Then* gather the rest of the info.

What you have gathers all the info (including all the `JOIN` work) for *all* the users, *then* sorts and peels off 25.

It will be something like:

```
SELECT  -- lots of stuff
    FROM ( SELECT  u.id,
                   CONCAT(u.lastname,' ',u.firstname) AS fullname
              FROM  fcf_users AS u
              JOIN  fcf_user_user_groups AS ug ON ...
              JOIN  fcf_users_userinfo AS ui ON ui.user_id = u.id
              WHERE  ug.group_id = '8'
                AND  ui.lrn_user = '0'
              ORDER BY u.lastname, u.firstname  -- now sargeable
              LIMIT 25
         ) AS u25
    JOIN ....  -- whatever tables are needed to get the rest of the columns
    ORDER BY u25.fullname  -- yes, again, but now using the CONCAT
    -- no limit here
```

Also:

```
u:  INDEX(lastname, firstname, id)
```

user_user_group is a "many-t0=many mapping" table?  If so, follow the indexing advice here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
Ditto for any other many:many tables.

Note how I put into the derived table only the tables needed to achieve the `LIMIT`.